# Am told that this JSON has multiple root elements, Help correct

Tags: arrays, json

How do I merge a JSON with Multiple root elements for instance

```json
{"a": 1}                
{"a": 2}        
{"a": 3}
```

Comment: Please provide more information on what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Put them in an array:

```json
[                   <-- root element...in this case an array
  {"a": 1},
  {"a": 2},            can nest other elements only
  {"a": 3}
]                   <-- root close. Adding another element after this is invalid.
```

Comment: Thanks This actually worked, however am trying to add the same on shopify but wont accept